# clearing html text files with data from mysql

Tags: javascript, php, reset

i have the below form which is taking data from mysql server and making calculation but when use the reset button i couldnt clear the text fields that has data from my sql
the short of the code is below i might have deducted some necessary parts but the code is working just except the reset button  to .
could you please help me with that.

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#reset").click(function(){
       $("#find").val("");
       $("#Editbox13").val("");
       $("#Editbox14").val("");
       $("#Editbox17").val("");
    }); 
});

</script>

<?php

$find=$_POST["find"];
$find = preg_replace('/ı/', 'i', $find);  
$find = strtoupper($find);

mysql_connect("*****", "*****", "****") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("kaliteler") or die(mysql_error());

$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM egearge3 WHERE BASECODE LIKE '%$find%' ");

$result = mysql_fetch_array( $data );


?>

</head>
<body>
<div id="wb_Form1" style="position:absolute;left:5px;top:4px;width:1346px;height:798px;z-index:69;maxwidth:device-width;">


<form name="PRICE_CALCULATION" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="_parent" id="Form1" onsubmit="return ValidatePRICE_CALCULATION()">

<input type="text" id="Editbox13" style="position:absolute;left:123px;top:406px;width:90px;height:30px;line-height:30px;z-index:17;" name="Editbox13" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['Button2'])&&$find!="") {echo $result['REALWIDTH'] ;} ?>" tabindex="12" spellcheck="false" placeholder="000">

<input type="text" id="Editbox14" style="position:absolute;left:344px;top:408px;width:90px;height:30px;line-height:30px;z-index:28;" name="Editbox14" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['Button2'])&&$find!="") {echo $result['REALWEIGHT'] ;} ?>" tabindex="13" spellcheck="false" placeholder="000">

<input type="text" id="Editbox17" style="position:absolute;left:2px;top:663px;width:1314px;height:63px;line-height:63px;z-index:41;" name="Editbox17" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['Button2'])&&$find!="") {echo $result['TYPE']."-".$result['COMPOSITION']."-".$result['PROCESS'] ;}else{echo "";}?>" spellcheck="false" placeholder="product details" rows="2" >

<input type="submit" id="Button1" name="submit[]" value="giveprice" style="position:absolute;left:516px;top:608px;width:222px;height:44px;z-index:42;" formaction="insert2.php" >

<input type="text" id="find" style="position:absolute;left:556px;top:222px;width:132px;height:36px;line-height:36px;z-index:64;" name="find" value="<?php echo $find ; ?>" spellcheck="false">

<button type="submit" id="Button2" onclick="window.reload(true);return false;" name="Button2" value="getir" style="position:absolute;left:562px;top:282px;width:71px;height:46px;z-index:65;" formaction="page8.php" >getir</button>

<input type="reset" id="btnReset" name="reset" value="Reset" style="position:absolute;left:642px;top:282px;width:56px;height:44px;z-index:68;" onclick="reset()">
</form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try using **.on** instead on directly **.click** .

Comment: Please, stop using mysql_* functions... They are old, unsecured and broken, were deprecated in PHP 5.5, and completely removed in PHP 7.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 errors:

- first you are attibutting a onclick event in btnReset to a function that doesn't exist (reset())
- in $(document).ready you are setting an object that doesn't exist (#reset). Should be #btnReset
- even if you have gotten the name right in $(document).ready it wouldn't work because the reset button is of type reset which just puts the initial values in the field and doesn't allow onclick events to be set.

So to correct: remove onclick="reset, change $("#reset").click to $("#btnReset").click and change type="reset" to type="button".

**Edit**

I'm taking for granted that you included the script line that loads jQuery. If you didn't do this, you also have to include

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

before `<script>` tag or the $ command won't work. Notice that this is one of many ways to include jQuery. Use whatever you want, but don't forget it must be loaded before the code in the `<script>` tag runs

Like this:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#btnReset").click(function(){
            $("#find").val("");
            $("#Editbox13").val("");
            $("#Editbox14").val("");
            $("#Editbox17").val("");
        }); 
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wb_Form1" >
        <form name="PRICE_CALCULATION" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="_parent" id="Form1" onsubmit="return ValidatePRICE_CALCULATION()">
            <input type="text" id="Editbox13" value="whatever">
            <input type="text" id="Editbox14" value="whatever">
            <input type="text" id="Editbox17" value="whatever">
            <input type="submit" id="Button1" name="submit[]" value="giveprice" formaction="insert2.php" >
            <input type="text" id="find" value="whatever">
            <button type="submit" id="Button2" onclick="window.reload(true);return false;" formaction="page8.php" >getir</button>
            <input type="button" id="btnReset" name="reset" value="Reset" >
        </form>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: first of all thank you for your time. i have tried this but its still not working :(

Comment: have you made these three steps ? remove onclick="reset, change $("#reset").click to $("#btnReset").click and change type="reset" to type="button"

Comment: i think it was my fault in making the change now its working . thank you very much for all your help

Comment: If the answer was useful to you, you can also upvote, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

A `reset` button resets the form to the initial state, which means: the state it was loaded with. If you rendered stuff on the server, the `reset` button takes the form back to that state.

If you want to clear it using the given Javascript code, you should have a look at the proper selector: you reference a non-existing element with the ID `reset`, while the reset button has the ID `btnReset` - and it uses a JS handler calling the method `reset()` which is not given in your example code.

So, after all: there are multiple issues with your code. Is any of this helping you out already?